# Alternative to putting an include inside a While loop

Tags: loops, include, while-loop

I have a chunk of PHP code that I'd like to include on a number of different pages but be able to update in one location (hence my use of an include file). However, the chunk of code needs to appear inside a while loop -- specifically inside a while loop that is echoing out MySQL rows.

However, there are roughly 200 rows in the MySQL query I'm echoing, so having an include in the loop really slows things down. I've tried making what's in the include file a function, like shown below, then including once at the top of the page and referencing the function inside the loop, but it it doesn't seem to work (I just don't get any data in the variables I'm setting, etc.)

How does one put a chunk of code inside a loop without using include?

Thanks very much.

```
function CYCalc()
{


  // If the company's current fiscal quarter
  // is equal to the current calendar quarter,
  // use the company's fiscal years as calendar years

  if ($UniverseResult[CurQ] == "Q1" && $UniverseResult[CurYear] == "2012") {
    $C2011Sales =  number_format($UniverseResult[SalesYear2]/1000000,1); 
    $C2012Sales =  number_format($UniverseResult[SalesYear3]/1000000,1);
    $C2011EPS =  $UniverseResult[EPSYear2]; 
    $C2012EPS =  $UniverseResult[EPSYear3];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember PHP's scoping rules. Variables defined in the global scope are not visible inside functions unless you explicitly declare them as global within the function:

```
<?php

$x = 7;

function y() {
   echo $x; // undefined
}

function z() {
   global $x;
   echo $x; // 7
}

function a($x) {
   echo $x; // 7
}
```

For your CYCalc() to work, you'd need to declare `$UniverseResult` global as per `z()` above, or pass it in as a parameter as per `a()` above.

Comment: Thanks very much Marc -- so I assume each and every variable inside the function needs to be declared as global? Even items inside the MySQL array (e.g. $UniverseResult[SalesYear3])?

Comment: If you're using a variable inside a function that was defined OUTSIDE, then yeah, it should be globalized. But don't just globalize everything, only the ones that are necessary, and try to avoid global variables, period. They have their occasional place, but use parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks again Marc -- I've globalized the variables I need inside the include function, and it looks like it's working --- but I think it's even slower than when I was just looping the include file. Is there a huge performance penalty for globalizing variables?

Comment: @Ben-Wilson: is SalesYear3 a variable or an index? it looks like an index to me, so you should put it in `'` to mark it as a string, e.g. `$UniverseResult['SalesYear3']` - otherwise it needs a `$` (the way it is now, php will try to use it as a constant). You don't need to pass all parts of $UniversalResult seperatly, they will be passed as a whole package